# Como hacer metodo boolean con atributo asignado en JAVA

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, javafx, java-ee

eestoy realizando otro ejercicio de practica mi duda es la siguiente:

Crear la clase AdminTelefono con los siguientes métodos:

1. activarMensajeria: no retorna nada, recibe un Telefono
   Si el telefono tiene operadora "movi", colocar tieneWhatsapp en true**

Crear la clase TestTelefono2, con un main, en el main:

1. Instanciar un Telefono y referenciarlo con la variable telf
   datos: operadora: movi
   numero: 098234234
   codigo: 20
2. Crear un objeto AdminTelefono y referenciarlo con la variable at
3. Invocar al método activarMensajería y pasarle como parámetro el objeto referenciado por telf
4. Imprimir los datos de telf, incluido el atributo tieneWhatsapp, que ahora se debe tener el valor true

Clase Telefono

```
    package com.cmc.directorio.entidades;

public class Telefono {

    // Atributos
    private String operadora;
    private String numero;
    private int codigo;
    private boolean tieneWhatsapp;

    // Constructor
    public Telefono(int codigo, String operadora, String numero) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.operadora = operadora;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.tieneWhatsapp = false;

    }

    // Getter and Setters

    public String getOperadora() {
        return operadora;
    }

    public void setOperadora(String operadora) {
        this.operadora = operadora;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public boolean isTieneWhatsapp() {
        return tieneWhatsapp;
    }

    public void setTieneWhatsapp(boolean tieneWhatsapp) {
        this.tieneWhatsapp = tieneWhatsapp;
    }

}
```

Clase AdminTelefono

```
    package com.cmc.directorio.entidades;

public class AdminTelefono {

    public  activarMensajeria(Telefono telf) {
        if (telf.getOperadora() == "movi") {

        } else {
            System.out.println("La operadora es distinta");

        }
    }

}
```

TestTelefono

```
package com.cmc.directorio.test;

import com.cmc.directorio.entidades.Telefono;

public class TestTelefono {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Telefono telf = new Telefono(10, "09941234123","movi");
        
        System.out.println("COdigo: " + telf.getCodigo());
        System.out.println("Operadora: " + telf.getOperadora());
        System.out.println("Numero: " + telf.getNumero());
        telf.isTieneWhatsapp();
        
    }
    
    

}
```

Asigno al constructor al atributo false como se menciona pero no entiendo como sacar el true, me confundo porque especifica el dato del atributo movi que no se como ejecutar en una condicional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas.

1. Para comparar String en Java debes usar `equals`, no  `==`.
2. Para cambiar el estado de la propiedad usarías el método `setTieneWhatsapp()`.

### `Clase AdminTelefono`

```
package com.cmc.directorio.entidades;

public class AdminTelefono {

    public  activarMensajeria(Telefono telf) {
        if (telf.getOperadora().equals("movi")) {
            telf.setTieneWhatsapp(true);

        } else {
            System.out.println("La operadora es distinta");

        }
    }

}
```

3. En el `main` tienes que imprimir la propiedad, como haces con las otras.

   ```
   System.out.println("Whatsapp?: " + telf.isTieneWhatsapp());
   ```

### PD:

Te recomendaría que no mezcles convención de nombres (inglés/español). Y que si es posible uses convención en inglés. Es más simple y útil cuando se trabaja en proyectos donde intervienen varios programadores o cuando escribes un repositorio de código o librería.

En el caso del método que nos ocupa, el verbo que aplica sería `has` (*tiene*), no `is` (*es*), así, el método quedaría como `hasWhatsapp()`. Si el método fuera para decirte si es un teléfono móvil por ejemplo entonces sí se usuaría `is`, viniendo a ser `isMobile()`. Esos pequeños detalles son importantes en convención de nombre.

Comment: Al realizar la ejecución de igual forma el objeto que cree como se evidencia en Main me sale como false, es decir no me toma esta condicion de activarmensajeria

Comment: Ya lo resolvi agradezco tu respuesta, solo quedaba agregar la a main AdminTelefono t = new AdminTelefono();
   t.activarMensajeria(telf);